# Typesetting of matrices with multi-row and column entries

Tags: matrices

[image]

I want to make a matrix-vector product in latex that is similar in style to what is shown. Suppose that the entire matrix and vector is 3x3 and 3x1, but i want to group the entries as shown and separate with dotted lines, while keeping the original "size" of the matrix, to show how the entries are grouped. How would one go about doing that?

Comment: Have a look at the `nicematrix` package

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What have you tried so far? Please show us a short compilable TeX code we can copy and play with! Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `nicematrix` package has tools for this. The `\Block` command spans both columns and rows as specified. `columns-width=auto` forces all columns to be the same width.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\[
\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits=2mm}
\begin{bNiceArray}{c:cc}[columns-width=auto, margin]
A_{11} & \Block{1-2}{A_{12}} & \\ \hdottedline
\Block{2-1}{A_{21}} & \Block{2-2}{A_{22}} \\[4ex]
&&
\end{bNiceArray}\;
\begin{vNiceArray}{c}[margin]
\Block{1-1}{x_1}\\ \hdottedline
\Block{2-1}{x_2} \\[4ex]
\\
\end{vNiceArray}
\]
\end{document}
```

Or if you want dashed lines, you can define a `custom-line`. Note that `tikz` must be loaded for this option.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix, tikz}

\begin{document}
\[
\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits=2mm, custom-line={letter=I, tikz=dashed, total-width=\pgflinewidth, command = hdashedline}}
\begin{bNiceArray}{cIcc}[columns-width=auto, margin]
A_{11} & \Block{1-2}{A_{12}} & \\ \hdashedline
\Block{2-1}{A_{21}} & \Block{2-2}{A_{22}} \\[4ex]
&&
\end{bNiceArray}\;
\begin{vNiceArray}{c}[margin]
\Block{1-1}{x_1}\\ \hdashedline
\Block{2-1}{x_2} \\[4ex]
\\
\end{vNiceArray}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do exists also a \hdashedline instead of \hdottedline?

Comment: @Sebastiano: Not built in, but you can define it yourself. I updated my answer with this information.

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Thank you very much. I have upvoted you yesterday. Best regards.